# Returning an empty array instead of null

Tags: javascript

I am wanting to return an empty array. However, it keeps returning null. How can I resolve this in my code

I am wanting the mentions array to return blank on this occasion, but it keeps coming back as null

```
function getTweetData(tweet) {
  let hashtag = tweet.match(/#\w+/g)
  let atSign = tweet.match(/@\w+/g)

  let tweetObj = {
    tags: hashtag,
    mentions: atSign,
    tagCount: 0,
    mentionCount: 0,
    length: tweet.length
  }

  if (tweet.match(/#/g))
    tweetObj.tagCount++

  if (tweet.match(/@/g))
    tweetObj.mentionCount++

  console.log(tweetObj)
  return tweetObj
}
```

Test

```
it('Should increase the count of tags', () => {
    expect(getTweetData('My awesome tweet about #coding')).to.eql({ tags: ['#coding'], mentions: [], tagCount: 1, mentionCount: 0, length: 30 })
  });
```

Comment: Nothing in the code creating `tweetObj` attempts to create a property called `mentions`...? Literally, searching for `mentions` just finds it in the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
let hashtag = tweet.match(/#\w+/g) || []
let atSign = tweet.match(/@\w+/g)  || []
```

Answer (score 5):

You can modify:

```
let atSign = tweet.match(/@\w+/g)
```

to:

```
let atSign = tweet.match(/@\w+/g) || []
```

Adding `|| []` will assign an empty array to `atSign` in a case where your regex returns null